# EventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread from Caliburn.Micro throws : System.InvalidOperationException: 'Not initialized with dispatcher.'

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await, caliburn.micro

I'm working on a UWP app. I'm using caliburn.micro framework for MVVM.
I've overriden the ShellViewModel's `OnViewLoaded(object view)` method to make an awaited call to an asynchronous login method as follows:

```
protected async override void OnViewLoaded(object view)
{
    base.OnViewLoaded(view);
    if (GetView() is UIElement page)
    {
        page.KeyboardAccelerators.Add(_altLeftKeyboardAccelerator);
        page.KeyboardAccelerators.Add(_backKeyboardAccelerator);
    }
    await StartLoginProcess();
}
```

```
private async Task StartLoginProcess()
{
   /// validations go here
   await _eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThreadAsync(new AuthenticationFailedMessage()).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

When I try to run the application, it throws the following exception:
[exception at login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnF8J.png)

Initially I thought that the usage of `ConfigureAwait(false)` in `StartLoginProcess()` is wrong, but removing it makes no difference.

Has anyone faced this kind of issue?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_eventAggregator.PublishOnCurrentThread(message);` solved the problem. I think I was invoking the `_eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread(message)` from the wrong context. It essentially requires to be invoked from within the UI thread itself, where as in my case it was not so.